# Qt QPushbutton:hover not work

Tags: qt

The following is my Qt codes:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->result_button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{border:none};
                                  QPushButton:hover{border-image:url(:/images/splitter_button_left)}");
}
```

When I hover my mouse over result_button, the image does not display. Why? and how to make the button look like transparent only when hovering show?

Comment: Where is your file extencion: png or jpg? Your path is not correct.

Comment: My path is correct. I use the .qrc to manage the resources. When I delete this part "QPushButton{border:none};" only using "ui->result_button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton:hover{border-image:url(:/images/splitter_button_left)}")", the result is correct. But the button has the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet is wrong. It should be:

```
ui->result_button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{border:none;} QPushButton:hover{border-image:url(:/images/splitter_button_left);}");
```

Note the positions of the `;` characters.